# Will Index Errors Cause Security Issues?

Tags: php, post, error-handling, indexing, undefined

I need to ask a simple question to make sure, being stupid and my first attempt in making this feature I forgot to add in isset() when needed now if I remove error_reporting(0); it will come up these error and I don't feel like re-writing the functionality or removing each error one by one and yes eventually I re-write it probably when I have the time.

The question is will having these errors cause any security or performance issues?

Thanks!

Comment: Notices aren't errors in every case. They likely bloat up log files however, which is how they mostly impair performance. You'll have to look at those individually to asses if they introduce logic faults. There's no broad generic answer regarding security impacts. (Applying super-silent isset substitutions however aren't a useful generalization either.)

Comment: notices are not a huge deal atleast the functionality still works as will

Comment: Correcting these errors would probably taken less time than posting this question

Comment: actually no it only took me a secound to post this question and i need to fix 30 errors lets just say it's poorly written by my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will have a very minor, practically un-noticable affect on execution time, as if PHP is going to report that a variable is not set, it has to execute a little more code.

The only instance in which I think this could become a security issue is if you have error reporting enabled on a live site. In which end-users can see a snippet of code and what panguage you are using.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: ive added up the top of the code error_reporting(0); and thanks for the answer ;)
Should of coded it probably in the first place but guess people make mistakes

Comment: What panguage do you use Kohjah? ;)

Comment: I use the English lang.

Answer (score 0):

it could cause some problems of performance if there is more than 1000 or 10000 errors notice , depending of your configuration, off course.

Comment: in future I just add isset() and make sure no more of these errors get produced
thanks ;)
and there are 20 of these errors which is time consuming to resolve